# How to say 'X, let alone Y' in Japanese?

Tags: grammar, phrase-requests

How to say `X, let alone Y` in Japanese?

For example, how would one translate:

> I don't know hiragana, let alone kanji.
>
> He couldn't boil water, let alone prepare a dinner for eight.
>
> I haven't enough time to look in the mirror, let alone go to see you.

Would one use `も`? `どころか`? From [Yahoo!辞書](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch/3/2na/03061900/):

> 赤ん坊は走るどころか歩くこともまだできない。
> The baby cannot walk yet, much less run.
>
> 野鳥観察に出掛けたが，つぐみどころかすずめも見えなかった。
> I went bird watching, but I could not find even a sparrow, to say nothing of a thrush.

Is that the appropriate grammar pattern?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think you can use:

> - ～どころか～も/すら/すらも・・・ない
> - ～はおろか、～も/すら/すらも/さえ/さえも・・・ない
> - ～はおろか、～など・・・はずがない/はずもない
> - ～はもちろん（or もちろんのこと）、～も/すら/すらも/さえ/すらも・・・ない
> - ～ない。まして（or ましてや）～など・・・はずがない/はずもない/わけがない/[言]{い}うに[及]{およ}ばない

"I don't know hiragana, let alone kanji":

> - [漢字]{かんじ}どころか、[平仮名]{ひらがな}も（or すら/すらも etc.）[知]{し}りません。
> - 漢字はもちろん、平仮名も（or すら/すらも etc.）知りません。
> - 漢字はおろか、平仮名も（or すら/すらも etc.）知りません。
> - 漢字はおろか、平仮名など知るはずもありません。
> - 平仮名は知りません。まして（or ましてや）漢字など、知るはずが(or はずも/わけが)ありません/漢字など、言うに及びません。

"He couldn't boil water, let alone prepare a dinner for eight":

> - 彼は８[人分]{にんぶん}の[食事]{しょくじ}を[作]{つく}るどころか、お[湯]{ゆ}を[沸]{わ}かすことも(or すら/すらも etc.)できなかった。
> - 彼は８人分の食事を作ることはおろか、お湯を沸かすことも（or すら/すらも etc.）できなかった。
> - 彼は８人分の食事を作ることはおろか、お湯を沸かすことなど、できるはずもなかった。
> - 彼は８人分の食事を作ることはもちろん、お湯を沸かすことも（or すら/すらも etc.）できなかった。
> - 彼はお湯も沸かせなかった。まして（or ましてや）８人分の食事を作るなど、できるはずが（or はずも/わけが）なかった/８人分の食事を作る(こと)など、言うに及ばなかった。

Answer (score 7):

That's right; どころか is one way to express the "much less" English phrase in Japanese.

まして or ましてや is another common way to express this.

For example:

> 私はピアノを弾{ひ}くことはできない。ましてや楽譜{がくふ}は読めない。

Note: These type of phrases tend to be written using Hiragana these days, but some of the Kanji (associated with these expressions) are listed on [this reference site](http://ja.glosbe.com/en/ja/much%20less), as well.